# How can I obtain the private key from a DER file in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, private-key

I want to obtain the private key like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I did this using Openssl console with this command:

`pkcs8 -inform DER -in '...keyfile.key' -passin pass:12345678a -out '...OutputFile.key.pem'`

The thing is I need to be able to do this in different environments where I cannot guarantee OpenSSL console will be installed.

I'm using Netstandard 2.0

Just to update and potentially help someone, I manage to solve this using. PemUtils and a openSSL class I found made in c#.

you can find this openSSL class here.

https://gist.github.com/njmube/edc64bb2f7599d33ca5a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .net library does not provide any way to deal with PEM private key files.  You will need to use a third party like [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) or [PEM-utils](https://github.com/huysentruitw/pem-utils) to deal with it.